# reference_wrapper: make_pair VS Class Template Argument Deduction (CTAD)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction, ctad

Why does `make_pair` and Class Template Argument Deduction (CTAD) not agree on which type to generate?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
    int myInt = 5;
    std::reference_wrapper<int> myIntRef = myInt;
    auto myPair = std::make_pair(myInt, myIntRef);
    std::pair My2ndPair(myInt, myIntRef);
    std::cout << typeid(myPair).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(My2ndPair).name() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
St4pairIiRiE                       // std::pair<int, int&>
St4pairIiSt17reference_wrapperIiEE // std::pair<int, std::reference_wrapper<int> >
```

**Update:**

Why do the deduction guides for `std::pair` not include a guide for `std::reference_wrapper` like `make_pair` has an overload?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Becase `make_pair` is *smart*:

```
std::reference_wrapper<int> myIntRef = myInt;
auto myPair = std::make_pair(myInt, myIntRef);
```

This calls the [overload unwrapping the `std::reference_wrapper<int>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/pairs.spec#9):

```
template<class T1, class T2>
  constexpr pair<unwrap_ref_decay_t<T1>, unwrap_ref_decay_t<T2>> make_pair(T1&& x, T2&& y);
```

On the other hand, the the [implicitly-generated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#Implicitly-generated_deduction_guides) [deduction guides for `std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/deduction_guides) take the types as-is.

Comment: Any idea as to why the deduction guides are not "smart"?

Comment: @Jonas Because nobody made them smart. `std::pair{...}` is deduced using the [implicitly-generated deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#Implicitly-generated_deduction_guides).

Answer (score 4):

There is special rule for [std::make_pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair)

> The deduced types V1 and V2 are `std::decay<T1>::type` and `std::decay<T2>::type` (the usual type transformations applied to arguments of functions passed by value) **unless application of `std::decay` results in `std::reference_wrapper<X>` for some type `X`, in which case the deduced type is `X&`**.